# Grails "war" command, how to set system property

Tags: grails, system-properties

I'm running `grails prod war` to create my app's `.war` file.  The problem is, I need to somehow set a system property that can be accessed in `grails-app/conf/Config.groovy` when that .war is being built.

How can I do this?  Grails version 2.1.0

Answer (score 1):

You need to set this property when the war is being launched, not when it's being built. If the app is being hosted by Tomcat (or similar) you would typically adds this as a parameter to the java command that launches Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to provide system properties when the app is being launched.  I'm asking if there's a way to do so when the app is being compiled.

Answer (score 0):

```
grails -Dproperty=value prod war
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this command answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.